# Adobe InDesign interactive/animation: Can I change object layer options

Tags: adobe-indesign, animation, interactive

tldr; Is there any way that I can use animations to change the opbject layer options of an .ai file in an interactive InDesign presentation, avoiding my need for 10 slides for a single .ai?

---

I do a lot of presentations in InDesign. I use graphics that I create in Illustrator a lot. An example would be a graph, where I actually have one .ai file with 10 different plots in a same set of axes to compare in a presentation, or show the gradual buildup of a concept this way.

Currently, I use no animations or anything - I simply duplicate the slide a dozen times in InDesign, and edit the object layer options for each new slide to gradually tell my story.

I was recently looking at making interactive presentations in InDesign as the 'next level' of improving their quality. Is there any way that I can use sometihng like animations to change the opbject layer options, avoiding my need for 10 slides for a single image?